# stored procedures in phpmyadmin server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

**I have created stored procedures in **MySQL** database on my local machine and when i generate the script to run it on the host server i have this error**

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation
```

**and this is the code**

```
  CREATE DEFINER =  `User_name`@`host_name` PROCEDURE  `InsertOrder`
```

and this `user_name` take all the  privilege ,so any one can help please?

Answer (score 0):

As [the manual says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-procedure.html):

> If you do not have the [`SUPER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege, the only permitted user value is your own account, either specified literally or by using [`CURRENT_USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user). You cannot set the definer to some other account.

You must either issue the command using an account which has the `SUPER` privilege, or else change the `DEFINER` to your current user account (which is the default if it's omitted).

Comment: how can i get the SUPER privilege ,do you know ??

Comment: A user who already has the `SUPER` privilege will need to [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html) it to you.